# Intellij : how to go back when navigationg through classes in Java

Tags: intellij-idea

In eclipse I have the very useful possibility to go back when I navigate throug classes/interfaces.

[image]

I don't find this option in Intellij. Any help please ?

Comment: Her is the list of default keymap for windows, linus and mac.
https://resources.jetbrains.com/storage/products/intellij-idea/docs/IntelliJIDEA_ReferenceCard.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There should already be a default keymap for navigating backward in your code journey.  Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>, and then select `Keymap` from the left hand menu.  Then, do a search for `back` in the dialog box at the top of the window.  Scroll down, and you should see `Navigate <= Back` as one of the options.  You may see what the current keyboard shortcut is.  If you don't like it, and want to change it to something else, you may do so.  For navigate back, Intellij defaults to <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>Left Arrow</kbd>, while Eclipse defaults to just <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>Left Arrow</kbd>.

Comment: To add to this, use `ctrl + shift + E` to show the list of Last edited locations or `ctrl + E` to see visited files. As a matter of fact, I find `ctrl + shift + a` to search actions which shows shortcuts as well, in case I have forgotten one.

Comment: OK ! Thx a lot ! But there are only keymaps and not an icon as in Eclipse. But anyway it's pretty fine

Answer (score 0):

In IntelliJ (Linux),

Press `shift + alt + left key` for navigating backward in your code journey.

Press `shift + alt + right key` for navigating forward in your code journey.